# Dual monitor between windows 7 and windows 10

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, multiple-monitors

I have two laptops, one with windows 10 and the other one with windows 7; my goal is to extend the windows 10 monitor on the other monitor. Is it possible to do it?

So far I found only a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LOLMpOa2nos) which shows how to extend the monitor between two windows 10 PCs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand you are looking to extend your desktop to the other computer.

Windows does not have this functionality, so this requires a third-party product.

Some I know of are: [spacedesk](https://spacedesk.net/),
[ZoneScreen](https://zoneos.com/zonescreen/).

Comment: Hello @harrymc are they free?

Comment: These are free. There exist also commercial products.

Comment: spacedesk doesn't support windows 7, and zonescreen doesn't support windows 10. Could you suggest me a software which supports both windows 7 and windows 10 please?

Comment: Not free ones, and even the commercial ones are starting to disappear. Example MaxiVista, Splashtop Wired XDisplay.

Comment: spacedesk works on windows 7 as well (I tried it today)